Eigenvectors of symmetric normalized adjacency matrix
I've been trying to get a better understanding of the phenomenon of over-smoothing in the context of GNNs. In particular, I'd like to be able to characterize the steady state of a particular signal after repeated convolutions, when applied with no non-linearity and no weight multiplication.
I think repeated convolutions like this would take the form:
$\tilde{A} = D^{1/2}AD^{1/2}$ 
$h(x) = \tilde{A}^kx$
where k is the number of convolutions, and A and D are the adjacency and degree matrices with added self loops.
My fuzzy understanding is that since an adjacency matrix normalized in this way is symmetric, it is also diagonalizable, so this can be expressed as:
$h(x) = U\Lambda^kU^Tx$
where U contains the eigenvectors of the normalized adjacency matrix, and $\Lambda$ contains the eigenvalues on the diagonal.
The normalized adjacency matrix is non-negative, and in this case I am working with a connected graph, so I believe it should be irreducible as well. And as a result, I think the Perron–Frobenius theorem states there should be a max absolute value of 1 for the eigenvalues, and the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues with absolute value 1 should be strictly positive.
As k goes to infinity, the eigenvalues with absolute value less than one shrink to 0, and so the result of the equation above would be to project x onto the eigenvector(s) corresponding to the max eigenvalue. And so the steady state of my repeated unweighted linear convolution would be the projection of the initial vector onto the dominant eigenvector.
I've been trying to test this understanding with an example, and the result isn't matching my expectations. In particular, I'm finding that while there is an eigenvalue of 1, the corresponding eigenvector is not strictly positive, and the projection of the initial value onto this vector doesn't resemble the steady state my repeated convolution converges to.
Here is the example code I'm using to test my assumptions:
def adj_from_edges(num_nodes, edge_index):
    adj_matrix = torch.zeros((num_nodes, num_nodes), dtype=torch.float)
    adj_matrix[edge_index[0], edge_index[1]] = 1
    adj_matrix[edge_index[1], edge_index[0]] = 1
    adj_matrix = adj_matrix + torch.eye(adj_matrix.size(0))
    return adj_matrix

def normalized_adj(adj_matrix):
    degree = adj_matrix.sum(dim=1)
    degree_sqrt = torch.diag(torch.pow(degree, -0.5))
    return degree_sqrt @ adj_matrix @ degree_sqrt

adj_matrix = adj_from_edges(37, item.edge_index)
norm_adj_matrix = normalized_adj(adj_matrix)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = torch.linalg.eigh(norm_adj_matrix)

Here is where I see unexpected results - the eigenvectors all have a mix of positive and negative values.
I'm fairly new to spectral theory, so I imagine I've made an incorrect assumption along the way, but I've been struggling to spot it. If someone could point out where I've misunderstood, it would be a tremendous help!
The values I use for my test graph are:
edge_index = torch.tensor([[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3, 3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7, 7,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36], [ 1,  2,  3,  0,  2,  3, 24, 27,  0,  1,  3, 27, 28,  0,  1,  2,  4,  5, 28,  3,  5,  6, 29,  3,  4,  6,  7, 29,  4,  5,  7,  8,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10,  6,  7,  9,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12,  7,  9, 11, 12,  9, 10, 12, 26,  9, 10, 11, 25, 26, 14, 15, 16, 25, 13, 15, 16, 25, 13, 14, 16, 17, 13, 14, 15, 17, 15, 16, 18, 19, 17, 19, 20, 17, 18, 20, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 30, 20, 22, 23, 30, 35, 20, 21, 23, 35, 20, 21, 22, 33,  1, 27, 28, 29, 12, 13, 14, 26, 29, 11, 12, 25, 28, 29,  1,  2, 24, 28, 29,  2,  3, 24, 26, 27, 29,  4,  5, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 20, 21, 33, 34, 35, 32, 34, 36, 31, 33, 34, 36, 23, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 21, 22, 30, 33, 34, 31, 32, 33, 34]])


I did end up figuring out my mistaken assumption here. torch.linalg.eigh returns the eigenvectors along the columns of the matrix not the rows!
